# how to center css grid and keep it when expending

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am adding pics with explanations.

***Desired result:***
[image]

[image]

[image]

***Actual sad result: (not in the middle)***
[image]

[image]

The last pic is close to be in the middle but it is not.
I am using css grid and react mdl. I am of course adding my code.
Thanks!

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Card,
  CardTitle,
  CardActions,
  Button,
  CardMenu,
  IconButton,
  CardText
} from "react-mdl";

class ProjectCard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { projectName: "", projectDescription: "", links: {} };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Card shadow={6} style={{ borderRadius: "6px" }} onHover>
        <CardTitle
          style={{
            color: "#fff",
            height: "176px",
            background:
              "url(https://blog.lunarlogic.io/images/react-logo.png) center / cover"
          }}
        >
          Welcome
        </CardTitle>
        <CardText>
          Todo::
          <br /> - add project description <br />- animate background
        </CardText>
        <CardActions border>
          <div style={{ marginLeft: "50px" }}>
            <Button colored>GitHub</Button>
            <Button colored>Description</Button>
          </div>
        </CardActions>
        <CardMenu style={{ color: "#fff" }}>
          <IconButton name="share" />
        </CardMenu>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}
export default ProjectCard;
```

```
.app-content {
  background: #f1f2f6; /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
    to right,
    #f1f2f6,
    #f1f2f6
  ); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    #f1f2f6,
    #f1f2f6
  ); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

.navbar-header {
  background: #2484c4; /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(
    to right,
    #2484c4,
    #2484c4
  ); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    #2484c4,
    #2484c4
  ); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
}

.nav-bar a {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.drawer-menu a {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.linkedin i {
  display: block;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.github i {
  display: block;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.projects-grid {
  display: grid;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  grid-template-columns: max-content max-content max-content;
  padding-top: 2em;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  grid-row-gap: 50px;
  grid-column-gap: 50px;
  justify-items: center;

}

.grid-item {
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}
```

```
import React from "react";
import { Tabs, Tab, Grid, Cell } from "react-mdl";
import ProjectCard from "./ProjectCard";

class Projects extends React.Component {
  state = { activeTab: 0 };

  handleChange = tabId => {
    this.setState({ activeTab: tabId });
  };

  toggleCategiries = () => {
    switch (this.state.activeTab) {
      case 0:
        return (
          <div className="projects-grid">
            <div className="grid-item">
              <ProjectCard />
            </div>
            <div className="grid-item">
              <ProjectCard />
            </div>
            <div className="grid-item">
              <ProjectCard />
            </div>
            <div className="grid-item">
              <ProjectCard />
            </div>


          </div>
        );
      case 1:
        return <div className="typescript-projects"></div>;
      case 2:
        return <div className="java-projects"></div>;
      case 3:
        return <div className="c-projects"></div>;
      case 4:
        return <div className="c++-projects"></div>;
      case 5:
        return <div className="swift-projects"></div>;
      case 6:
        return <div className="python-projects"></div>;
      default:
        return <div>lala</div>;
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="categories">
        <Tabs
          activeTab={this.state.activeTab}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          ripple
        >
          <Tab>React</Tab>
          <Tab>TypeScript</Tab>
          <Tab>Java</Tab>
          <Tab>C</Tab>
          <Tab>C++</Tab>
          <Tab>Swift</Tab>
          <Tab>Python</Tab>
        </Tabs>
        {this.toggleCategiries()};
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Projects;
```

I have added the relevant components.
I have tried so many things but none of them worked for me.
It feels weird because I am vertically aligning elements all the time with this technique. maybe it is related to react mdl.

Comment: Can you provide your code in a sandbox like https://codesandbox.io ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve your problem using three layers of `div`, i.e. wrapping the items within the container in another div with a [flex model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) like this -

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 400px; /* Width of your outermost container */
  height: auto;
}

.wrapper{
  width: auto; /* Wrapper takes the width of the content */
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item{
  height: 80px; /*Height and width of the item itself */
  width: 80px;
}
```

Check [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-xdpyxu).